# Ansible conditionals - Wildcard match string

Tags: ansible, ansible-playbook

I have the following conditional in an Ansible task:

```
when: ec2_tag_Name == 'testhost01'
```

It works fine, however I would like to match a wildcard on the `ec2_tag_Name` field.

So something like this

```
when: ec2_tag_Name == 'testhost*'
```

The goal is to match anything like `testhostx` `testhost12` `testhostABC` etc etc just anything matching `testhost` at the start of the string.

Is this possible? Can't seem to get it working.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

From [Testing Strings](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_tests.html#testing-strings):

> To match strings against a substring or a regex, use the “match” or “search” filter

In your case:

```
when: ec2_tag_Name is match("testhost.*")
```

Comment: I had also found that `when: 'testhost' in ec2_tag_Name` can do a similar thing, it doesn't restrict it being at the start of the string - so yours is definitely the right way to do it. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

This works as well.

```
when: "ec2_tag_Name.startswith('testhost')"
```

You can combine logical operators as well like ***and***  and  **or**

Comment: Where is this documented? I could not find it